# On Windows 10 no automatisation possible , .bat .lnk cmd ignore Administrator

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I wanted to implement a simple .bat with commands like rmdir & mklink on a virtual guest system  , and there they won't run as intended.

*when running .bat as Admin , it wont execute rmdir (symbolic link still remains)*

when setting "Run as Admin" to a .lnk file, it wont run as Admin

only running the the command terminal as admin and pasting the commands makes them execute as intended...

UAC is turned off  surely there is another setting i am missing ...

One the host Windows 11 the bat work without "Run as Admin"

Edit : seems like i got overheated , all .bat run as intended via manually "Run as Admin" , but problem still remains that shortcuts wont execute as "Admin" despite the Property set ...

Edit2 : Problem was using an alternative File Explorer , after setting Property "Compatibility -> Run as Administrator" problem was resolved.

Comment: Can you provide a MRE? The fact you are unable to remove a directory despite elevating the permissions of the script indicate something else is going on that isn't related to UAC.

Comment: sry , was to fast , edited the Question

Comment: Are your files marked as executable?  Do you have admin rights on this machine?

Comment: sry guys , mistake on my part ...

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: please look at Edit2